# wrong date order with strtotime()

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

is anyone has a clue why is this `strtotime();` code is not working properly?

`$time= "05/08/2017 18:30";` (5th Aug)

`echo (strtotime($time));`

displayed result is: 1494268200 which is 08/05/2017 18:30 (8th May)

The "$time" value is coming from date-time picker. Displayed correctly, the $time variable is displayed correctly as well. So I don't understand why is the strtotime not convert it properly.

Just in case here the DateTimePicker codes line.

```
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
    format:'d/m/Y H:i',
    formatDate:'d/m/Y H:i',
    minDate:new Date(),
    startDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: `Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.` - [src](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, issue solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `/` to `-` and then you can go fine:-

```
<?php

$time= "05/08/2017 18:30";

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$time)));// you can change possible fomat according to your wish
```

Output:-https://eval.in/841263

Reference:-[Date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Note:- check @aynber comment and read it carefully

Answer (score 0):

You need to Replace / to - and then you can go fine:

```
<?php $time = '05/08/2017 18:30';
$time = str_replace('/', '-', $time);
echo date('d/m/Y H:i', strtotime($time));
?>
```